# Lifetime scoped dependency can't be located using MediatR .Net Core 3.1 Web API & SignalR

Tags: .net-core, signalr, autofac, mediatr

Having

```
builder.RegisterType<UserDetails>().As<IUserDetails>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

and

```
builder.RegisterType<Mediator>().As<IMediator>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Got Null after for UserDetails in a **nested** mesagge using Mediator:

```
public class UserChannel : Channel
{
    public IUserDetails CurrentDetails { get; set; }
    private UserChannel ( IUserDetails data )
    {
        CurrentDetails = data ;
```

> data has the current scoped value

```
    }


public async Task<AskForUserDetails.Response> AskForUserDetailsAsync( AskForUserDetails.Request emptyRequest )
        {
            return await Mediator.Send( new ReadUserDetailsFromScope() );
        }


}
```

Here is the current value being null

```
public class ReadUserDetailsFromScope
{
    public IUserDetails CurrentDetails { get; set; }
    private ReadUserDetailsFromScope ( IUserDetails data )
    {
        CurrentDetails = data ;
```

> data value is null for nested

```
    }


public async Task<ReadUserDetailsFromScope.Response> AskForUserDetailsAsync( ReadUserDetailsFromScope.Request emptyRequest )
        {
            return await Mediator.Send( ***this.CurrentDetails***  );
        }


}
```

Autofac v5.0.0
Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection v6.0.0.
MediatR v7.0.0.
MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection v8.0.0
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common v3.1.3

Complementary configuration

```
 public class UserDetails : IUserDetails
    { } 


IServiceCollection services
services.RegisterAssemblyPublicNonGenericClasses( IUserDetails ).AsPublicImplementedInterfaces( ServiceLifetime.Transient );
```